# Как наложить один грид-элемент на другой пользуясь именованными областями?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

Способом ниже - понятно, от одного числа до другого и z-index.

```css
.setka {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  color: white;
}
.blue {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
.green {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="setka">
<div class="blue">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="green">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

А как получить аналогичный эффект с помощью grid-template-areas? Какая форма записи? (если существует)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

аналогичный эффект можно получить с [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas), однако расположение второго блока все равно придется настраивать вручную, для перекрытия с помощью свойства [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).

```css
.setka {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-areas: 
  ".    green green"
  "blue blue  .    "
  ".    .     .    ";
  color: white;
}
.blue {
  grid-area: blue;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  
}
.green {
  grid-area: green-start / green / 3 span;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="setka">
<div class="blue">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="green">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

```css
.setka {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-areas: 
    ".    green green" 
    "blue green green" 
    ".    green green";
  color: white;
}

.blue {
  grid-area: blue-start / blue-start / blue-end / 2 span;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.green {
  grid-area: green;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="setka">
  <div class="blue">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="green">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: класс, пасиба за варианты